# add more feature in webform component

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have to to give add more button in webform fieldset. add more can be done in multiple times.
What are the best approches.

I try to used webform_addmore module. but it cannot resolve my issue because in this module i have to pre created fieldset. so it can not be unlimited.

All suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can do drupal node theming. Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Find the drupal webform node id
2. Edit the node, like, node--node_id.tpl.php
3. All the variables comes in $node, you can see, by printing edit. you can customize your webfrom from this.